# What's the technical term for "cryptography based on elliptic-curve pairing"?

Tags: translation, technology

The study of modern crytography is more than just about keeping information secret - public-key cryptography studies methods to exchange secrets in open public (key exchange, public-key encryption) and guaranteeing the authenticity of messages (digital signatures).

Even beyond that, is a vastly larger realm with the likes of identity-based encryption/signature, attribute-based encryption, etc. All of which are enabled by elliptic-curve pairing.

I'm expected to report to my superior about those and teach newly hired staff about how to use them. So the question is how should I translate the terms such as "pairing-based cryptography" and "elliptic-curve pairing"?

I don't want to repeat the mistake like that of FireFox translating "key exchange group" as "密钥交换组" (inside its developer tools for inspecting network connections) when the formal mathematical term for "group" is "群". So when Google Translate says "配对", I suspect that such generic term is not what the scientific community use.

Comment: What have you tried? Why hasn't it worked?

Comment: @Mou某 Google translation says "配对", but I'm not sure if the scientific community formally use that term, as it's a pretty generic translation for "pairing".

Comment: You should add that information to your post. Unless prior research effort is clearly indicated, it's very easy for your question to get closed.

Comment: Just like FireFox (as of version 84) still errornously translate "key exchange group" as "密钥交换组", where as the mathematical term for "group" is “群”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pairing is either 配对 or 对, even in cryptography. 椭圆曲线对 is used in [the SM9 standard](https://github.com/guanzhi/GM-Standards/blob/master/GMT%E6%AD%A3%E5%BC%8F%E6%A0%87%E5%87%86/GMT%200044.3-2016%20SM9%E6%A0%87%E8%AF%86%E5%AF%86%E7%A0%81%E7%AE%97%E6%B3%95%20%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%89%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86%EF%BC%9A%E5%AF%86%E9%92%A5%E4%BA%A4%E6%8D%A2%E5%8D%8F%E8%AE%AE%20.pdf). But 椭圆曲线配对 is also in common use.

There's a book entitled 《基于配对的密码学》.

Using "对" alone sounds more technical, but also (in my opinion) phonetically confusing or inelegant in certain contexts.